# I want to modify array-column output when fetched

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This is my data table image
[image: this is my data table image]

my blade file

```
@table([
    'id' => 'Persons.index',
    'xhr' => route('api.manage-dup-api'),
    'ns' => 'PersonsIndex',
    'columns' => $columns ?? [],
    'filters' => $filterTable ?? [],
    'params' => [
        'filters_live' => false,
        'selectable' => true,
        'toolbar_style' => 'fixed'
    ]
])
```

this is a query which passes data to a data table [API]

```
 $q->with('user')
            ->with('user.roles')
            ->select(
                'persons.*',
                'birth->date as birthdate'
            )->`enter code here`whereIn('id', $id)->orWhereIn('old_id_CONINET', $coninet_ids);
        return $this->outputList($q, $request);
```

as shown in the picture I want to remove ["] from the CONINET_ID table

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the whole column, or you want to remove these 3 specific characters `[` and `]` and `'` leaving just `"22312", "4323245"`

Answer (score 0):

you are storing an array of strings in the DB.

you can convert the array values to int:

```
array_map('intval', $array);
```

you can also [create an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) on your eloquent model

```
public function getOldIdConinetAttribute($value)
{
    return array_map('intval', $value);
}
```

Comment: I want to show     238612, 812381 in CONINET_ID col can we do it through the query.

Answer (score 0):

It would better if you give some detailed info. As of now details mentioned above can not explain your code. As of my understanding, I suggest you to check Yajra datatable plugin which will help you solving your issue.

or you can cast coninet_id to array by adding below code in your model.

```
protected $casts = [
'coninet_id' => 'array'
];
```